# Modify all frontend content

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I would like to modify all the frontend-content before it's rendered.

For example: Replace all strings like "foo" with "bar".

So now I got this:

```
public function boot()
{
    /*
     * Set the page context for translation caching with high priority.
     */
    Event::listen('cms.page.init', function($controller, $page) {
        dump($page);
    }, 100);
 }
```

This shows me a dump of `$page` - but how can I modify the content?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at third parameter `content` in `cms.page.postprocess` event.